# Embedding into $p$-adic complex numbers

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

As I'm reading notes about the Leopoldt conjecture, the following question came to my mind:

Let $\mathbb{C}_p$ be the $p$-adic complex numbers, i.e. the completion of the algebraic closure of the field of $p$-adic numbers $\mathbb{Q}_p$.
For a number field $K$ there are embeddings $\sigma: K \to \mathbb{C}$ and Dirichlet's Unit Theorem determines the structure of the units of this number field $\mathcal{O}_K^\times$ via a logarithm map. 
Now, to construct the same for the $p$-adic complex numbers, one takes the logarithm map $\log_p: k^\times \to k$ which is defined for a local field $k$ via $\log_p(p) = 0$ and the convergent series $\log_p(1+x) = x - x^2/2 + ...$ for every principal unit $1+x \in U^1_k$.

Now there is a map

$$K^\times \to \prod_{\sigma \in Hom(K,\mathbb{C}_p)} \mathbb{C}_p^\times$$

that I do not understand. Where do the embeddings into the $p$-adic complex numbers come from? I know that the $p$-adic complex numbers and the complex numbers itself are isomorphic as abstract field, however, not as topological fields.

Can somebody help me with this question?
Thank you!

Best, 
Tom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know anything about the Leopoldt conjecture, but regarding embeddings into $\mathbb{C}_p$.... Note that $K$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, and $\mathbb{C}_p$ is an algebraically closed field containing $\mathbb{Q}$, so there have to be embeddings of $K$ into $\mathbb{C}_p$. Abstractly this is the same way you get embeddings of $K$ into $\mathbb{C}$. To be more explicit, you can use the primitive element theorem to pick a primitive element $\theta$, so that $K = \mathbb{Q}(\theta)$, and then the minimal polynomial $p(x)$ of $\theta$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ must split over $\mathbb{C}_p$ since $\mathbb{C}_p$ is algebraically closed. If $\theta_1, \dotsc, \theta_n$ are the roots of $p(x)$ in $\mathbb{C}_p$, then $\theta \mapsto \theta_i$ define the $n$ possible embeddings of $K$ into $\mathbb{C}_p$.

Answer (score 2):

Fix an embedding of $C_p$ into $C$. Then any embedding of K into $C_p$ becomes an embedding of K into $C$ , and that's all, no topology is involved. Regarding Leopoldt's conjecture at p, the approach via p-adic log in order to construct the p-adic regulator works only for totally real fields. For general number fields, there is a more convenient conceptual approach. Let $E_1$ denote the group of units of K which are congruent to 1 mod every prime $v$ of K above p. Let $U_1,v$ be the local units congruent to 1 mod $v$ . By the diagonal embedding of $E_1$ into the direct sum of the $U_1,v$ 's, the closure of $E_1$ becomes a $Z_p$-module, and Leopoldt's conjecture states that the $Z_p$-rank of this closure is equal to the $Z$-rank of $E_1$. The best reference for all this, in my opinion, is Washington's book "Introduction to cyclotomic fields", §§5.5, 13.1 and 13.5.